# Yii 1.14 notice Undefined offset: 0 in CUrlManager.php

Tags: php, yii, crash, notice

Hello i am facing this notice in my web application that powered on Yii 1.14 on a sub domain in godaddy and it crashes my application.

Undefined offset: 0

/home/uname/public_html/some_dir/yii/framework/web/CUrlManager.php(656)

```
 public function __construct($route,$pattern)
 {
     if(is_array($route))
     {
         foreach(array('urlSuffix', 'caseSensitive', 'defaultParams', 'matchValue', 'verb', 'parsingOnly') as $name)
         {
            if(isset($route[$name]))
                 $this->$name=$route[$name];
        }
         if(isset($route['pattern']))
             $pattern=$route['pattern'];
         $route=$route[0];
     }
     $this->route=trim($route,'/');

     $tr2['/']=$tr['/']='\\/';

     if(strpos($route,'<')!==false && preg_match_all('/<(\w+)>/',$route,$matches2))
     {
         foreach($matches2[1] as $name)
             $this->references[$name]="<$name>";
     }


$this->hasHostInfo=!strncasecmp($pattern,'http://',7) || !strncasecmp($pattern,'https://',8);
```

Comment: apparently `$route[0]` isn't set

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Jonan : Yep but the problem this is a core code from Yii 1.14 and it works on my local host with no problems

Comment: @Clément Malet i don't think so.

Comment: @HamzehAlDarawsheh Then you'll have to give more details on your problem. All we can they is that `$route[0]` is not set. What do you expect it to be ?

Comment: @Clément Malet, the app was working on my local host when i uploaded it to go daddy this error showed, the error from yii core as you can see.

Comment: I guess you have notices turned off on localhost, that's why you see this error only on remote host.

Comment: @Timur No they are on.

Comment: Many times errors like this are problems with your config.php file. Can you provide us with the contents of the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs if your config is corrupt.
Check your config in:

```
['components']['urlManager']['rules']
```

If you have set an empty array at this position, you'll get the reported error.

```
return array(
    'components'    => array(
        'urlManager'   => array(
                'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'
                        => '<controller>/view', // fine

                    array(), // Won't work!!
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'
                        => array(), // Won't work!!
                ),
        )
    )
)
```

Please check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) and update to the most recent version 1.1.15 which is an important security update.

Comment: Before few minutes i solved the problem, it was empty rule as you mentioned -i have no idea how it got deleted it looks i have a ghost in my host-, thanks a lot sir, unfortunately i can't up vote you because my reputation still low, regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case that was duplicate of code('urlFormat'=>'path',) like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.components.UrlManager',
        'urlFormat'=>'path', //duplicate
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            ...
        ),
        ),
    ),
```

in my 'urlManager' config.
I have deleted one of them('urlFormat'=>'path',) and error had gone